# WPD C# Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, wpd

I am new to Windows Phone developing and I am trying to copy a  file from PC to Windows Phone Documents folder. I read and tried what is written in this article [Copy files with WPD to Windows Phone C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839822/copy-files-with-wpd-to-windows-phone-c-sharp#new-answer). The original article is https://dzone.com/articles/creating-apis-for-mobile-iot-apps. Unfortunately I got an error of ArgumentException in the line:

```
targetStream.Write(buffer, bytesRead, pcbWritten);
```

I think it's related to the parameter ParentObjectID, when I call the method:

```
device.TransferContentToDevice(@"H:\temp\QuestPhone\Pesquisas.db",@"G:\Documents");
```

I tried to replace "G:\Documents" by "Windows Phone:\Documents", and "Phone:\Documents" and "Windows Phone:\Phone\Documents" but without success.

So, how can I specify the "logical drive" where my Windows Phone device is connected to?

Answer (score 0):

After some time I got a solution. The correct ParentObjectID is @"o1". "o1" is the ID of documents folder on the device.